# URL "/" functionality change

Tags: php, javascript, html

Can I ask how to change the last "/" of the URL change its function as "?" so that I don't get any page error when trying to enter `..test/act/100` in URL.

I want the URL above to be processed as `..test/act?100` so that I wont get page error and I can do whatever I want to do in parameter that being passed (100).

Another thing is I want to leave `..test/act/100` as it is in URL.

Comment: mod_rewrite in Apache?

Answer (score 0):

For exactly what you asked for:
Create or edit your existing .htaccess file, by adding this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test/act/([^/]*)\.php$ /test/act?$1 [L]
```

But i suspect you may have meant

```
..test/?act=100
```

In which case change the .htaccess file to this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test/act/([^/]*)\.php$ /test/?act=$1 [L]
```

EDIT:
I do apologise, im guessing the '...' means anything before '/test'?
In that case just remove the ' ^ 'after RewriteRule